# Average number of holes supporting a puck on an air hockey table

Tags: probability, area

How would I go about finding the average number of holes supporting a puck on an air hockey table? I'm trying to find a generalized equation using the distance between holes, the area of the puck, and the area of the table (and more if needed). The holes are too small to calculate the area of, so i'm wanting to consider them points. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: two most likely arrangements for the holes are a square lattice or a hexagonal lattice.